# If $(A + I)^4 = 0$, $A$ is non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ be an n × n real matrix such that $(A + I)^4 = 0$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix, how to prove that $A$ is non-singular?

Answer (score 12):

Let $\lambda$ be any eigen value of $A$. Then $(\lambda+1)^4=0$ that means $\lambda\neq 0$. So, $A$ is nonsingular

Answer (score 9):

If $A$ were singular, then there would be a non-zero vector $x$ with $Ax=0$ and therefore $(A+I)x=0+x=x$.  But then $(A+I)^4x=x$, whereas we're given that $(A+I)^4x=0$.  (This is essentially Jlamprong's answer, without using the word "eigenvalue" or the letter $\lambda$.)

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively one can note that

$(A + I)^4 = 0 \tag{1}$

may be written as

$A^4 + 4A^3 + 6A^2 + 4A + I = 0, \tag{2}$

which after some easy algebraic maneuvering yields

$A(A^3 + 4A^2 + 6A + 4I) = (A^3 + 4A^2 + 6A + 4I)A = -I, \tag{3}$

showing that

$A^{-1} = -(A^3 + 4A^2 + 6A + 4I). \tag{4}$

Since $\exists A^{-1}$, $A$ is nonsingular.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 5):

Denote $B =  A + I$. Since $B^4 = 0$ then we have

$$- I = B^4 - I = (B - I)(B^3 + B^2 + B + I) = A (B^3 + B^2 + B + I)$$

So $-(B^3 + B^2 + B + I)$ is the inverse of $A$ (hence $A$ is not singular).